# Which version of Ardour should I download?

Tags: software-installation, architecture

I am using 32 bit version Ubuntu and I am getting this :
https://community.ardour.org/s/buy_anon

Should I get the Linux x86 or source code for all platforms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 32 bit Ubuntu version so you need to download "**Ardour 4.2 for Linux x86**".

"**Ardour 4.2 source code for all platforms**" is aimed at developers, it is just plain source code which need to be [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) to be run. It is not for end user.